# This question is about vectors: "Find the projection of $v=2i+3j$ in the direction of $w=4i-2j$."

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

This question is about vectors: "Find the projection of $v=2i+3j$ in the direction of $w=4i-2j$."

I'm not exactly sure how I should approach this problem. I've been told I have to use dot product, but that didn't help as much. Can someone show me how I'm supposed to solve this problem?

Comment: Think dot product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since,
$$V.W=\Vert V\,\Vert\Vert W\Vert\,Cos\theta$$
and $$V\,Cos\theta=Projection\,of\,V\,in\,the\,direction\,of\,W$$
Therfore, 
$$V.W=\Vert W\Vert V_w$$
$$V_w=\frac{V.W}{\Vert W\Vert}$$
So, yo have to find dot product of $V$ and $W$, then divide it by the magnitude of $W$.

Comment: For this, would I get just a sinlgle value? I ended up getting 1/(sqrt 6)

Comment: Yes, Projection is just a magnitude.

Comment: Projection is how many part of first vector is in the direction of second vector.

Answer (score 0):

The projection of $\underline{a}$ onto $\underline{b}$ is $$\frac{\underline{a}\cdot\underline{b}}{|\underline{b}|}$$

Comment: So (v*w)/(|w|)?

Comment: Yes that's it..

Answer (score 0):

For any vectors $\vec u, \vec v\neq 0$, the horizontal magnitude of $\vec v$ on the axis of $\vec u$ is $|\vec v|\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the 2 vectors.

For the direction of the projection vector, it is just the unit vector of $\vec u$, that is $\displaystyle \frac{\vec u}{|\vec u|}$.

Therefore, the projection vector is $\displaystyle \frac{\vec u}{|\vec u|}\cdot|\vec v|\cos\theta=\frac{\vec u\cdot\vec v}{|\vec u|^2}\vec u$.

And the length is $\displaystyle\frac{\vec u\cdot\vec v}{|\vec u|^2}\cdot|\vec u|=\frac{\vec u\cdot\vec v}{|\vec u|}$.